# Calculate radius with part chord

Tags: circles

I'm trying to calculate the radius for the following problem based on the intersection of the blue and red lines (length and angle)

[image]

I tried simple trigonometry to calculate half the length of the chord = 150mm

[image]

But not sure how to calculate the sagitta which i could then use to calculate the radius as per [Sagitta - The height of an arc or segment](https://www.mathopenref.com/sagitta.html)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark radius $=r$. Making a triangle from the centre to the end of the blue line, we can use the law of cosines:
$$
r² = (770-r)^2 + 238^2 - 2\times 238 \times (770-r) \cos{141}
$$
from which we solve $r \approx 489.23$

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both @steven gregory and @Matti P.for the answer

The following is the equation solved for r

`r = (x^2 + y^2 - 2 * y * x * cos(a)) / 2*(x - y * cos(a)`


x = 770
y = 238
a = 141
r = 489.23